# Javascript not pushing object to array properly

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently working on a dress app and I've come across an issue that has cost me days, multiple coffees and head scratches!

Basically, I'm trying to return an array of all the dress owners profile data.

So it goes:

getDressData() => {
  
- Store dress details
  
- Store dress owner

},

getOwnerData() => {
  
- Loop through all dress owners
  
- Get their profile data

},

resolve() => {
  
- Return dress and filter data
  
- Return dress owner profile data

}

Here's the code:

```js
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var db = firebase.firestore();
        var dresses = [];
        var filters = [];
        var dressOwners = [];
        var ownerData = [];

        var dressCollection = db.collection('dresses');
        var ownerCollection = db.collection('account');
        var dressesRef = dressCollection.orderBy("date", "desc");
        
        dressesRef.get()
        .then(function(doc) {       
            if (!doc.empty) {
                doc.docs.forEach(function(doc) {
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        var item = doc.data();
                        dresses.push({
                            'dressId' : doc.id,
                            'colour' : item.colour,
                            'credit' : item.credit,
                            'date' : item.date,
                            'description' : item.description,
                            'images' : item.images,
                            'owner' : item.owner,
                            'size' : item.size
                        });

                        if(filters.filter(x => x.size == item.size).length == 0) {
                            filters.push({"size" : item.size, "colours": [item.colour]});
                        } 
                        else {
                            var index = filters.findIndex((x => x.size == item.size));
                            
                            if (!filters[index].colours.filter(x => x.colours == item.colour).length > 0) {
                                filters[index].colours.push(item.colour);
                            }
                        }

                        if (dressOwners.indexOf(item.owner) === -1) {
                            dressOwners.push(item.owner);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .then(function(){
            for (let i = 0; i < dressOwners.length; i++) {
                ownerCollection.doc(dressOwners[i]).get()
                .then(function(doc){
                    if (doc.exists) {
                        item = doc.data();
                        ownerData.push({                               
                            'uid' : doc.id,
                            'displayName' : item.displayName,
                            'feedback_neg' : item.feedback_neg,
                            'feedback_pos' : item.feedback_pos,
                            'registerDate' : item.registerDate,
                            'address' : item.address,
                            'email' : item.email
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        .then(function(){
            resolve({
                "dresses" : dresses,
                "ownerData" : ownerData,
                "filters" : filters
            });
        });
    });
```

Here is what it returns:

[What the Promise returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVGKn.png)

As you can see from the image, both arrays return the correct data. However, if you look at the first array, it displays '[]' and the second '(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]'.

I'm trying to get the first array to return like the second array.

The issue is that i cannot get data from the first array. The dress array (2nd) I can get dress[i].colour etc

What am I doing wrong? Is it the way I'm resolving the arrays or is it an issue with the .then() structure of the code?

Comment: Both are showing some length, and first one too showing length:2

Comment: The issue is that i cannot get data from the first array. The dress array (2nd) I can get dress[i].colour etc.

Comment: You can reduce nesting in your code by inverting the `if` condition.  From `if (!doc.empty) { blah }` to `if (doc.empty) { return; } blah;`  You're nested 8 or 9-levels deep in some places.  This could help in readability.  The book *Code Complete* discusses too-much-nesting in section 19.4, where it suggests that more than 3 levels deep becomes confusing.

Answer (score -1):

If I'm not mistaken, if you don't return anything from a .then in a chain, then the .thens resolve immediately since they're not actually waiting on anything via an explicit return. Try returning dressOwners from the first .then and use the passed in data in the following .then

Then, in the following .then, where you're creating multiple promises in a for loop, collect those promises in an array and return the result of Promis.all(myPromiseArray) to get to the final .then in proper order.

Comment: `if you don't return anything from a .then in a chain, then all the .thens run more or less concurrently since they're not actually waiting on anything`  Can you cite that in documentation?  It doesn't sound correct.  The promise chain won't execute the next promise in the series until the previous set of promises has been resolved.

Comment: Right, but if I have a .then, and it doesn't return anything, then how does the following .then know to begin?  I believe it's basically immediately returned, it doesn't wait on any internal code to finish because it has no way of knowing the internal code is done without an explicit return.  I totally admit I could be wrong here, but this is the way I've always approached it.

Comment: It knows to begin when the previous promise has been resolved.  Promises are not required to resolve to a value.  They can resolve to nothing.

Comment: Nowhere in the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) does it say the promise chain will run concurrently.  That isn't possible in JS, anyway, considering that JS is *single threaded*.

Comment: If, in a .then, I do an asynchronous operation, and I dont return anything, then we don't know to wait for anything, and the promise resolves, chaining on to the next .then without waiting for the asynchronous operation to resolve.  So, maybe not concurrently, but in a synchronous order without waiting on the results of asynchronous operations as the dev may be intending.

Comment: No, that isn't how it works.  `new Promise((resolve, reject) => { console.log(1); resolve();}).then(() => console.log(2)).then(() => console.log(3)).then(() => console.log(4)).then(() => console.log(5))`  What order do you expect those lines to execute in?  They will *always* be in the same order, because no `then` will execute before its preceding promise has been resolved.  It has nothing to do with return values, at all.  **Return values from promises are not relevant to when `then` promise chains are resolved**.  They are resolved in order, one after the other, every time.

Comment: right, but if I say 

... .then(() => { someAsynchronousOperation() }).then(() => { someOtherAsynchronousOperationDependentOnTheFIrst() })

since I'm not returning the resultant promise of the first asynchronous operation, then the first .thee resolves immediately while that async operation is still ongoing, moving on to the next .then where another operation may be dependent on the results of that first async op.  However it doesnt know that async op finished because we didnt pass its promise as the return value of the preceeding .then

Comment: Your first then will auto-resolve to `undefined` once `someAsynchronousOperation()` has finished executing, not before.  The next `then` will not start execution until the previous one has finished executing and been resolved.  Again, and I cannot say this any more clearly, **return values are not relevant to when `then` chains are handled**.  The next `then` will *not* start while `someAsynchronousOperation` is still executing.  That is not possible.

Comment: Each `then` creates a new promise and chains it off the previous.  When the previous promise *is resolved*, with or without a return value, then the next promise in the chain will execute.  Read the documentation.  If `then` returns nothing, it automatically returns `undefined`.  The next promise in the chain does not care whether the previous promise resolved to a value or not; it only cares that it was resolved or rejected.

Comment: I'm not disagreeing with anything you're saying I think we're just miscommunicating

Comment: Your answer is wrong and I'm trying to explain why.  This isn't miscommunication.  This statement:  `However it doesnt know that async op finished because we didnt pass its promise as the return value of the preceeding .then`  is simply wrong.

Comment: So, given two .thens, the first making an asynchronous operation that it doesn't return the promise of, then how does the second .then know the result of the preceeding asynchronous operation.  Asynchronous operations don't block code execution, so it's not like the first .then would wait some indeterminate amount of time for it's contained async op to resolve before moving on to the next .then.  The first .then would simply resolve to undefined and the next .then would be left in the dark about the results of the preceeding async op - or worse, assume it completed